# Loop through similar named labels, assigning values to each one in Access Vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, for-loop, concatenation

I'm building a calendar in Access 2010 with a page that changes based on the month. There's Labels `lblDay1` - `lblDay37`. If the month is February (2018) the 1st will start on a Thursday with `Weekday` value being 4 (using `vbThursday`).

The `For` loop needs to go through each `lblDay#`. `lblDay4` needs to equal `1`, then `lblDay5 = 2`, `lblDay6 = 3` etc, up to 28 days.

The issue I'm having is concatenating the labels as shown below

```
For i = 1 to 37
   If i = Weekday(#01/02/2018#, vbMonday) Then
      "lblDay" & i & ".Value" = 1
```

I don't know how best to fix line 3 from throwing an error.

Comment: You're assigning an expression to an expression, i.e. that instruction doesn't *do* anything VBA can understand. What are you trying to achieve? You need to get a hold of the actual `Label` object, you can't assign to a string like this. `Set theLabel = Me.Controls("lblDay" & i)` and then do `theLabel.Value = 1`.

Comment: Since you are using Labels, you will need to modify the `Caption` property, as Labels do not have a `Value` property. I would instead recommend that you use a Textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you opt to use Textboxes in place of Labels, you could use something similar to the following function to populate the Textboxes with your day numbers:

```
Function PopulateDays(datRef As Date)
    Dim datVar As Date
    Dim intTbx As Integer
    datVar = DateAdd("d", 1 - Weekday(datRef, vbMonday), datRef)
    For intTbx = 1 To 37
        Controls("txtDay" & intTbx).Value = Day(datVar)
        datVar = DateAdd("d", 1, datVar)
    Next intTbx
End Function
```

The above assumes that your Textboxes are named `txtDay1`,`txtDay2`,...,`txtDay37`.

You would call the above with a date to serve as a reference to determine the week on which to start the numbering.

For example to populate the Textboxes for the month of February, you could evaluate the function using:

```
PopulateDays DateSerial(2018, 2, 1)
```

This would yield something like:

[image]